# DevExpress ASPxTreeList DataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, devexpress, treelist

I have 2 tables. `Branch` and `Department`
I need to show the information of Branches and Departments in a `TreeList`.

A Branch can have Sub-Branches and a Branch can have Departments also.
I am Maintaining the relation-ship of Branches in a table `Parent_Child_Branch`
and I am Maintaining the relation-ship of Branch and Department in a table `Branch_Department`.

How can I show the data in a `treelist`.

Actually, What I have done is :
I have joined the `Parent_Child_Branch` and `Branch` to get one result
and another join for `Branch_Department` and `Branch` and `Department` to another result.
and I have `Union All` both the results.

I am getting the `union` data , but I am getting the repeated Id's.
So, I cannot give a `keyID` to `TreeList`.

My Query :

```
var query1 = (from xx in VDC.SURVEY_PARENT_CHILD_BRANCH
              join yy in VDC.SURVEY_BRANCH on xx.PARENT_BRANCH_ID equals yy.BRANCH_ID
              join zz in VDC.SURVEY_BRANCH on xx.CHILD_BRANCH_ID equals zz.BRANCH_ID
              select new
              {
                  ParentBranchID = yy.BRANCH_ID,
                  ParentBranchName = yy.BRANCH_NAME,
                  ChildBranchID = zz.BRANCH_ID,
                  ChildBranchName = zz.BRANCH_NAME
              }).Concat(
                        from aa in VDC.SURVEY_BRANCH_DEPARTMENT
                        join bb in VDC.SURVEY_BRANCH on aa.BRANCH_ID equals bb.BRANCH_ID
                        join cc in VDC.SURVEY_DEPARTMENT on aa.DEPT_ID equals cc.DEPT_ID
                        select new
                        {
                            ParentBranchID = bb.BRANCH_ID,
                            ParentBranchName = bb.BRANCH_NAME,
                            ChildBranchID = cc.DEPT_ID,
                            ChildBranchName = cc.DEPT_NAME
                        }
                        );
```

and My TreeList is :

```
<dx:ASPxTreeList ID="TreeList_Branch_Departments" 
    runat="server" 
    KeyFieldName="ChildBranchID" 
    ParentFieldName="ParentBranchID" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
    Theme="BlackGlass" 
    Height="410px"
    Width="534px" 
    Font-Size="11px" 
    Font-Names="calibri">
    <Columns>
        <dx:TreeListDataColumn FieldName="ChildBranchName" VisibleIndex="0" />           
    </Columns>
    <SettingsBehavior ExpandCollapseAction="NodeDblClick" />
</dx:ASPxTreeList>
```

Hope, You Understood my problem.
Sorry for my communication.
Can anyone suggest me with a solution.

Comment: Why don't you contact DevExpress Support Team directly?

Comment: I already posted the question to DevExpress Support.But,for a quick response,I posted here :)